# how to close commons-httpclient connection in version 3.1

Tags: java, httpclient, apache-commons-httpclient

Please suggest a way to close httpclient connection, it causes hung thread generated in server.
org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient

```
HttpClientManager httpClientManager;
HttpClient httpclient = httpClientManager.getHttpClient();
PostMethod p = new PostMethod(url);

 try{
  httpclient.executeMethod(p);
} 
catch(HttpException e){}
finally{
 httpclient.close(); //not available in HttpClient
}
```

Using old 3.1 version of jar where there is no method in HttpClient class to close httpclient connection.
Due to connection is not closing in the end , it causes hung thread in server.

Comment: Does it hang in the executeMethod call? What happens in the server?

Comment: code written in client jar is very old and there is no finally block in code only try/catch. It hanged on execute method, throwing socket time out exception, connection refused exception and hung threads in server. On analysis, identified that connection should be closed to avoid hung thread, if close method is  not available, will  postMethod.releaseConnetion() work as same ?

Comment: Have you tried releaseConnetion? what happened?

Comment: Not possible to test hung thread issue in local server because it didn't generate, it can be tested only in prod. I think this will work, will push this in prod.